# How to create unique pointers in a loop C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am reading a `double` from the standard input and saving it into a variable `d`. I want to be able to do this an unspecified amount of times. I use the following code to create a pointer to `d`.

```
double *pd = new double;
pd = &d;
```

I then push this pointer into a constructed stack (list) class.  But whenever I push more than one double it changes all of them (the pointer is the same).

Ex. push 2 and get an array [2]. push 3 and get array [3, 3] instead of [3, 2].

Comment: Why don't you just push in the doubles themselves?

Comment: You're losing a pointer to dynamically referenced memory. bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*pd = d
```

instead of

```
pd = &d;
```

What you do is:

- you have `double d` variable on stack
- you create double and save its pointer in `pd` variable
- **then you save address to d variable in pd**
- and then you save address from `pd` on list

This means you have list of addresses to variable `d` (every single object on list is pointer to `d` variable).

Comment: Or you could do `double *pd = new double(d);` Even better, `whateverStack.push(d);`.

Comment: The stack used pushes a pointer so I have to create a pointer to push, unfortunately. But yes, thank you for the help!

Comment: @AstraMeyers, What does it do with the pointer? Perhaps you could push `&d` instead.

Comment: @AstraMeyers use a different stack then.

Answer (score 7):

Why are you using pointers at all?

```
std::vector<double> v;

double d;
while (std::cin >> d)
    v.push_back(d);
```

Or as chris points out:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<double>(std::cin),
          std::istream_iterator<double>(),
          std::back_inserter(v));
```

Comment: You can also initialize the vector with `istream_iterator`s for an identical effect.